# Make the review ban be specific to the queue where I failed the audit

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, review, review-audits, review-suspension

I recently failed two review audits of late answers at [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour), and due to the failure of review audits I was banned from reviewing late-answers which is fine.

Now what's the point behind preventing the user from reviewing close-votes, first posts, etc.?

If the user failed for late answers, the user should be banned from reviewing only late-answers. What's the reason behind banning the user from reviewing close votes after failure of late answer reviews.

Can we remove that ban? I can't see any valid point behind banning a user from all type of reviews, if the user makes mistake at one type of review ban him/her from only that type [e.g. late answers].

This kind of review policy really discourages user whom spend their valuable time in contributing to the site.

Comment: Well, review is review. Failing an audit is a red line: it means you did not pay attention. All queues require attention, hence it make sense to ban the user from all of them.

Comment: @ShadowWizard if the user accidentally made a mistake at one type of review and banning for entire thing doesnt sound good,it really discourages user whom reviews daily,for e.g even some moderators were the victim's of this http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24581890#24581890

Comment: Thing is, such mistake is trivial, it's not related to the type of review. It shouldn't happen, in any of the queues

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you're not paying attention and robo reviewing in one queue, why shouldn't we use that as evidence that you'll do exactly the same thing in every other queue?

The point of stopping you altogether is to get you to reflect on what you're doing wrong, not just move on and make the same mistakes somewhere else.

We actively want to discourage you from reviewing if you can't do it properly so that's working as designed I guess.